# Clonned Linux from USB

Tags: kernel, initramfs, dracut

I have several net-top-boxes, all of them has 32GB mSata ssd and linux OS (f25, I guess).
Almost all theese devices has same problem time to time, wont boot, freezing while posting, caused by SSDs. I found the way - unplug SSD, trying to boot and "hotplug" SSD, several tryings after, it boot up normaly. BUT its very uncomfortable solution - bring tools, open box, unplug... Changing SSDs to brand new ones, does not help me for long purpose, because, after week or two, new one will start same. I decieded to use USB drive as boot device. Cloned whole SSD using selfimage and restored on 64 USB drive, It looks like working but, after posting NTB logo, loads very slow and brings an errors:

```
Warning: /dev/NTBgroup/swap does not exist
Warning: /dev/NTBgroup/system.11.1.4 does not exist
Warning: /dev/mapper/NTBgroup/system.11.1.4 does not exist
```

And enters dracut emergency mode, after trying to exit from it

Writes
Not all disks have been found
You might want to regenerate your initramfs.

---

Everybody will notice how unfamiliar with linux I am, but I can do everything, just give me a tips, hints, I'll do :(

Comment: See https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/driver-api/ntb.html. And their mailing list would probably be a good place to ask for information on NTB drivers and issues.

Comment: Misunderstanding, i think... I was talking about Net-top-box, onelan product... its like a mini PC (PC box with small motherboard, single RAM slot, mSata (my case) slot and couple periferial ports (usb, HDMI, sound VGA).

Comment: I thought, someone can help, but... :(

Comment: Well, I did cloning using clonezilla, now all old problems and errors gone... system boots up, no emergency mode, but stuck on login screen without error